# Dynamically insert views

Tags: ember.js

I could well be handling this the wrong way so please suggest alternatives if this is the case.

Lets say I have a collection view for showing many events

```js
App.EventsView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  contentBinding: "controller.content",
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "event"
  })
})
```

a template for the view:

```js
<div class="event">{{ view.content.name }}</div>
```

and loading it into the app

```js
{{#if content.isLoaded}}
  {{ view "ScheduleApp.EventsView" }}
{{else}}
  Loading...
{{/if}}
```

Now this works great for displaying a list of events but I would like to insert these event into parts of the dom depending on their attributes. Basically I would like to call appendTo on these views but they're implicitly generated by ember magic that I'd like to retain. Is this possible or am I going to have to explicitly define these views and if so how would I do this to keep everything in sync with the EventsController content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically set which view should be used for each element. That would allow you to change the dom based on their attributes.

Check out the [PROGRAMATIC CREATION OF CHILD VIEWS](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html) in the API section.

Hope that helps.

---

If you are trying to put these into different parts of the page, rather than just listing them out, then I might suggest looking into the `control` helper.

If this is the case, can you give a little more information on an example of where in the DOM these might be used? Might it be better to handle them by different controllers all together?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Lets say I'm making a basic calendar app. It has 7 days each with their own "column" or section. Having thought about it it sounds like I'd have a DaysController with 7 days. Each day would then have events. I suppose I'm still struggling with this concept of there only being one instance of each controller. How can I use Events controller in 7 places without changing the content? In fact does changing the content matter or is the EventsController still aware of other events having changed content?

Comment: Yeah, I had a similar issue. I ended up using the `control` helper which let me have a separate controller for each model that needed to be handled. I need to look into the `CollectionView` and get a better understanding of that. [Here](http://jsbin.com/uxodex/3/edit) is a little example I did awhile back with `control`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of Events and each event has a type attribute, and types would be say
seminar, concert and sports

The content of App.EventsController has all the events

```
App.EventsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  seminars: function(){
    return this.get("content").filterProperty("type", "seminar");
  }.property("content.@each.type")
  concerts: function(){
    return this.get("content").filterProperty("type", "concerts");
  }.property("content.@each.type"),
  sports: function(){
    return this.get("content").filterProperty("type", "sports");
  }.property("content.@each.type")
})

App.BaseEventView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'event'
  })
})

App.SeminarsView = Ember.BaseEventView.extend({
  contentBinding: 'controller.seminars'
})

App.ConcertsView = Ember.BaseEventView.extend({
  contentBinding: 'controller.concerts'
})

App.SportsView = Ember.BaseEventView.extend({
  contentBinding: 'controller.sports'
})

App.EventsView = Ember.View.extend({templateName: 'events'});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="events">
  {{#if content.isLoaded}} 
    {{view App.SeminarsView}}
    {{view App.ConcertsView}}
    {{view App.SportsView}}
  {{else}}
    Loading...
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

Everything is now in sync with controller's content Thanks to **Computed Properties**

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Now how would this handle the case of event types being variable. Lets say the event types are user defined and I don't know how many there are nor what they are called.